# Check for empty row within spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Running over several csv files and i am trying to run and do some checks and for some reason for one file i am getting a `NullPointerException` and i am suspecting that there are some empty row.

So i am running the following and for some reason it gives me an `OK` output:

```
check_empty = lambda row : not any([False if k is None else True for k in row])
check_empty_udf = sf.udf(check_empty, BooleanType())
df.filter(check_empty_udf(sf.struct([col for col in df.columns]))).show()
```

I am missing something within the filter function or we can't extract empty rows from dataframes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [df.dropna()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=nafunctions#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna) to drop empty rows and then compare the counts.

Something like

```
df_clean = df.dropna()
num_empty_rows = df.count() - df_clean.count()
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but i would like to check the content of those rows so i have more clear idea of what's happening.

Comment: the wired  things that i got zero, but the same piece of code has works fine with dataframe resulted from dropna transfromation instead it throw the exception without the one dropna

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inbuilt option for dealing with such scenarios.

```
val df = spark.read
     .format("csv")
     .option("header", "true")
     .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED") // Drop empty/malformed rows
     .load("hdfs:///path/file.csv")
```

Check this reference - https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-csv.html#reading-files