# Is there a way to take the csv file as it is? ....can we stop spark putting the default name to the empty column

Tags: opencsv, pyspark

[csv-data](https://github.com/1576dkm/name)

**I wanted to delete the empty column from the dataframe**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test_Parquet").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
names = spark.read.csv("name.csv", header="true", inferSchema="true")
names.show()
```

**This is the dataframe created from name.csv file**

```
+-------+---+---+---+-----+----+
|   Name|  1|Age|  3|Class| _c5|
+-------+---+---+---+-----+----+
|Diwakar|   | 25|   |   12|null|
|Prabhat|   | 27|   |   15|null|
|   Zyan|   | 30|   |   17|null|
|   Jack|   | 35|   |   21|null|
+-------+---+---+---+-----+----+
```

**Spark by default gave name to the empty column as 1, 3,_c5 can we stop spark giving default names to the columns.**

**I wanted to have a dataframe like given below:**

```
+-------+---+---+---+-----+----+
|   Name|   |Age|   |Class|    |
+-------+---+---+---+-----+----+
|Diwakar|   | 25|   |   12|null|
|Prabhat|   | 27|   |   15|null|
|   Zyan|   | 30|   |   17|null|
|   Jack|   | 35|   |   21|null|
+-------+---+---+---+-----+----+
```

**and i wanted to remove the empty column in one go like:**

```
temp = list(set(names.columns))
temp.remove(" ")
names = names.select(temp)
names.show


+-------+---+-----+
|   Name|Age|Class|
+-------+---+-----+
|Diwakar| 25|   12|
|Prabhat| 27|   15|
|   Zyan| 30|   17|
|   Jack| 35|   21|
+-------+---+-----+
```

Comment: Do you want to get only the final df which empty rows are dropped? Or do you also need mid-state, empty rows with their col names are empty?

Comment: @shimo if we will get the dataframe with empty column then we can easily remove the empty column, otherwise we will have to remove each and every column separately.

Comment: You can get dropped result directly using drop option. Like [2nd answer of this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376449/check-for-empty-row-within-spark-dataframe)

Comment: @shimo it's not working.....

Comment: Sorry, it seems  in pyspark you need to drop col manually. Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322445/how-to-drop-all-columns-with-null-values-in-a-pyspark-dataframe